# mysql row_count() returns 0 (NAGIOS alerts)

Tags: mysql

How to understand the result of this row_count() ?

It shows -1 when I did on host.

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> select row_count();
    +-------------+
    | row_count() |
    +-------------+
    |          -1 |
    +-------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What does this mean at all ?

This is the NAGIOS alert I am receiving.

[Image for alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc24Y.png)

No external links please. I went through the mysql documentation, but didn't get much info from that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the docs (first result on Google): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count: *-1 if the statement returns a result set*

Comment: **Do not use any of the** `mysql_*` **functions**. [These have been deprecated since PHP 5.5, and outright removed in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). Consider using [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or better yet use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: It says "This applies to statements such as CREATE TABLE or DROP TABLE." Do you know how it applies ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the MySQL `ROW_COUNT()` function ...

That only has meaning in relation to a previous statement that was executed.

For example, if you execute an `UPDATE` statement, then follow that with a call to the `ROW_COUNT()` function, e.g.

```
 SELECT ROW_COUNT()
```

The `ROW_COUNT()` function returns the number of rows that were affected by the previous UPDATE statement.

The documentation explains pretty well the answer to the question you asked "What does [the return from the `ROW_COUNT()` function] mean at all?"

That function only has a meaning in relation to the previously executed SQL statement. The documentation gives some examples of how this function can be used.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

---

But I don't really think any of that has anything to do with the Nagios alert.

There is scant evidence that the Nagios service is invoking the MySQL `ROW_COUNT()` function. The only indication that this might be the case is the name that was assigned to the Nagios service. And that's tenuous... the Nagios service could be named anything.

The questions that spring to my mind are "What conditions is the Nagios service checking for? What is it really checking, what command is it running, and what values are being returned, and why are those values being returned?"

I have some suspicious about what the Nagios service is actually checking, but those are just guesses.

Comment: what to use this row_count() for ? if only it can let us know the previously executed statement.